# Upload multiple images parse.com javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a multiple upload in parse.com with javascript code.
I have managed to upload one image into a class but now i want multiple images to be uploaded in different rows.

I have tried this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    Parse.initialize("APPID", "JSKEY");
    function saveJobApp(objParseFile) {
        var jobApplication = new Parse.Object("imagemagazia");
        jobApplication.set("imagename", objParseFile);
        jobApplication.save(null, {
                success: function(gameScore) {
                     alert("succesfull save image");      
                },
                error: function(gameScore, error) {
                    alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
                }
            });
    }
    $('#submitId').on("click", function(e) {    
        PhotoUpload();
        });
         function PhotoUpload() {
        var test = [];   
        console.log("edw");
        var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
        for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        var file = fileUploadControl.files[i];
        //test.push(file);
        var name = file.name; //This does *NOT* need to be a unique name
        console.log(name +" : "+file);
        //}
       console.log(test);
       //var t = [];
        //for(j=0; j<test.length; j++){
        var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
        //t.push(parseFile);
        //var nw = t[i];
            parseFile.save().then(
                function() {
                    saveJobApp(parseFile);
                },
                function(error) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="business_form" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="profilePhotoFileUpload" multiple></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="submitId" value="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

UPDATE. with the above code i am trying to upload 3 images.
"1.jpg" "2.jpg" "3.jpg"

but it uploads only 3.jpg because its the last one.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed it's better to make a loop the function itself externally and not making a loop in the function.
if you try making it like this :

```
$('#submitId').on("click", function(e) {
    var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
    console.log(fileUploadControl.length);
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
            var file = fileUploadControl.files[i];
            var name = file.name; 
            PhotoUpload(name, file);
     }
    });
```

And then  :

```
    function PhotoUpload(objname, objfile) {    
        console.log(objname);
        console.log(objfile);
            var parseFile = new Parse.File(objname, objfile);
                parseFile.save().then(
                    function() {
                        saveJobApp(parseFile);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                );
    }
```

Also if want to add more than tree images, you just add this :

```
for (i=0; i<fileUploadControl.files.length; i++)
```